# How to grant datastore access to a service account?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I can't use cloud datastore with a service account. However it works when using sdk default credentials method (gcloud auth login).

The error is `Error rpc error: code = 7 desc = Not authorized.`.
I was able to grant access to a storage bucket, but I can't find anything like this for datastore.

How do I grant cloud storage access to a service account?

ps. I need this because I want to use datastore outside of app engine.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found the solution:

1. Create a service account from IAM & Admin console
2. Add service account as a member to IAM
3. Grant *Project > **Editor*** role to newly added member